# Inline sprites in Unity's text?

Tags: unity, sprites

How can I use different materials when using the tag for Unity's rich text syntax?

I want to be able to have sprites that are inline with my text without having to create custom fonts.

Here's what I have so far:
[image]
Here's the syntax that I'm using for the text in my image:

`Planetary <quad material=1 size=20 x=0.1 y=0.1 width=0.1 height=0.1 /> Intergalactic`

I'm guessing "material=1" refers to the material index of the Text object. How can I set it to use a different material altogether?

Is there a plugin or other resource that makes embedding icons in text easier?

Comment: Using a `quad` with [Unity's rich text](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StyledText.html) is the only way to go. The `material` attribute is the material at the "position in the renderer’s material array". I would preprocess or concat in the proper material index by looking through [`Renderer.materials`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-materials.html) to find the material you are after.

Comment: I'll give that a shot and get back with some results, thanks MLM!

Comment: This question is [cross-posted on Unity Answers](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/851705/inline-sprites-in-unitys-text.html). It seems that while rich text is supported, quads are not according to Tim C and Phil from Unity, see: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/sprite-icons-with-text-e-g-emoticons.265927/

Comment: [I've made an implementation that does this in UI Text](https://twitter.com/D_M_Gregory/status/680477412287578112) (as opposed to the quad method with TextMesh) by dynamically spawning & positioning child images. The details get a little complicated, but if it's useful to anyone I can write it up as an answer.

Comment: @DMGregor, I'd love to have you write up an answer or link to your code for your Sprited Image script.

Answer (score 2):

As the text system is still the legacy text system, you can't embed images in text. Only option would be to have a layout group and have separate text and image blocks

Alternatively, you can use an asset like TextMeshPro which has a new text implementation which supports this fully (and much more!)